# Rectangle over an existing image and then display the image

Tags: java, image-processing, zk

I am currently working on zk framework which is been provided by zkoss, I am able to display image in a web page, but I want to put red lined rectangles over some fields. I am trying this :

// draws rectangle over the buffered 
private void drawRectangles() {

```
Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();

Iterator iterator = setOfRectangles.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)iterator.next();
    graphics.drawRoundRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, 5, 5);
}
graphics.dispose();
```

}

I am calling this method in another method which reacts to the upload event.

I am also saving the up;loaded image in this class.

but this is not working, if I can some how get the image after all rectangles been drawn then I can put that image in web page, but I am not getting it how to achieve this.
Thank you all for reading and replying.

Comment: What's "not working" in your current approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and its working :

```
Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();

Iterator iterator = setOfRectangles.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)iterator.next();
    float thickness = 3.0F;
    Stroke stroke = graphics.getStroke();
    graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));

    graphics.drawRoundRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, 5, 5);
    graphics.setStroke(stroke);
    graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
}

wholeImage.setContent(image);
graphics.dispose();
```

After doing this load the whole image in

Answer (score 1):

In terms of general Java, to export a `Graphics2D` you actually want to get the `Graphics2D` from a `BufferedImage` and it's the `BufferedImage` you write out to a file.

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
for(Rectangle rect : setOfRectangles) {
    graphics.drawRoundRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.height, rect.width, 5, 5);
}
ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("myPicture.png"));
```

This is not related to ZK and you'll find plenty of references on SO and elsewhere. You'll end up with a regular image file that can be displayed in ZK like normal.

That said, I'd recommend an alternative approach. Depending on your specific use case, this can probably be done with pure CSS. CSS-Tricks has a nice tutorial titled "[Text Blocks Over Image](http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/)" which explores the idea. You don't need any text in your `div`, just slap a `border` on it, leave the `background-color` as `transparent`, and position it as you need.

Comment: Thank you for replying your idea is really nice, now I have only one trouble I am not able to find out how will I apply CSS dynamically, I want to apply CSS on a button event in zk page(.zul) from its controller. Any help about this would be appreciated. Reason for doing this is : I want to upload forms and its fields would be highlighted on this upload event. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can set CSS from Java using `setStyle` and `setSclass` but before you do that, post another question here on SO with a full explanation of your problem. Provide pictures of what you hope to achieve and example code of what you've tried. Without knowing this information I/we cannot recommend a particular approach.

Comment: thanks for your help, I came to know two more things about zk which I am going to use in my project... :) :) :)